# Have windows key (meta) trigger Gnome-do instead of Unity Dash (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, unity, shortcut-keys, unity-dash, gnome-do

On my laptop the Unity Dash often launches really slowly.  I might press the Windows button, and sometimes it will take up to 15 seconds to open, and the system becomes unresponsive during this time.  This is especially likely if I haven't opened the launcher in a few hours.

I have Gnome-Do installed, and I currently launch it with "Ctrl + Space", and it launches instantly and is very responsive.

I would like to swap my shortcut keys, so Meta (the Windows key) launches Gnome Do, but I can't figure out where to change the keyboard shortcut for the dash.  Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, partly found my answer.  The keyboard shortcut for launching the dash is not in the "Keyboard Settings" app, but you can change it from "CCSM" (Compiz Config Settings Manager).

1. Install ccsm `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Run ccsm, open "Desktop / Ubuntu Unity Plugin" settings page
3. Change "Key to Show Launcher" setting
4. In "All Settings / Keyboard", add a custom shortcut that launches `gnome-do`

This mostly works, for any shortcut other than the Windows (Super) key.  When I enter the shortcut as "Super L", it fails to launch.  Any other shortcut appears to work.

Comment: Just realised - disabling the "Win" key for the dash seems to disable all the other win shortcut keys for the launcher, some of which I use all the time.  Guess I'll have to leave it for now...

Comment: Any news on how to use it with `SUPER`?

Comment: No sadly.  And I'm still getting 10+ second lags opening the unity panel.  Which is weird when everything else on the laptop (including editing video, compiling code etc) is pretty snappy.  No idea why it's so slow, so annoying that I can't change it